# Set Image When Word Appears In Label From Array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel

I am trying to make an image view set to a certain image when a label displays a certain word from an array which is being randomised.

The picture is supposed to set to the image view when specific words are the text of the label from the array.

Here is the array:

```
    let freeMoodArray = ["Happy", "Sad", "Angry", "Annoyed", "Curious", "Bored", "Chilled", "Furious", "Excited", "Scared", "Emotionless", "Shocked", "Tired", "Sick", "Amused"]
```

Here is the random label text:"

```
self.moodAnswer.text = "\(self.freeMoodArray.randomElement()!)"
```

Now when I load the view, the image chooses a random word from the array which is working. Now, lets say it says `Happy`as the text of the label. 
I want to set a certain image only when it says happy.

Here is my code, which doesn't work: (this func is called in the `viewDidLoad()`)

```
    func emojiMood() {
    if moodAnswer.text == "Happy" {
        emojiImg.image = UIImage(named: "happy.png")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `emojiMood()` after setting the label's text, not from `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You know where you are setting the label, so why not set the image there?

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy I just relocated the function and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

how a but a variable and DidSet ?

```
// create a variable
var moodAnswer :  string = "" {
   didSet {
       // if or switchCase, set image only if the text is equal to Happy
       if moodAnswer == "Happy" {
          emojiImg.image = UIImage(named: "happy.png")
       }
       // always set text field with new updated text
       self.moodAnswerLabel.text = moodAnswer
   }
}

// in your code always set moodAnswer variable, this is more clean and also you set label and image only in a single place
self.moodAnswer = "\(self.freeMoodArray.randomElement()!)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but all I had to do was to relocate the call of my function and it worked.